# c++ general int array and vector iterator

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, templates, iterator

In the following code, I need to define an iterator which can iterate on both `vector<int>` and `int[100]`. How to define `mi` here?

```
template<class arraytype>
void array_show(arraytype array, size_t arraySize)
{
    // how to define mi????
    for (mi = array; array != m.end(); array++)
        std::cout << " " << *mi << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Either use `auto`, or take in an iterator pair whose type you can deduce.

Comment: no need to use iterators. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example below. The importantpart is to use `arraytype&` - a reference, this way regular array is not decayed to pointer - this way it is possible to read its size inside array_show.

```
template<class arraytype>
void array_show(arraytype& array, size_t arraySize)
{
    // how to define mi????
    for (auto mi = std::begin(array); mi != std::end(array); mi++)
        std::cout << " " << *mi << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<class arraytype>
void array_show( const arraytype &array )
{
    for ( const auto &x : array ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    std::vector<int> v( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    array_show( a );
    std::endl( std::cout );

    array_show( v );
    std::endl( std::cout );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Another approach is to use iterators. For example (Here are shown the both function definitions)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<class arraytype>
void array_show( const arraytype &array )
{
    for ( const auto &x : array ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <class InputIterator>
void array_show( InputIterator first, InputIterator last )
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type value_type;
    std::copy( first, last, 
               std::ostream_iterator<value_type>( std::cout, " ") );

    std::cout << std::endl;     
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    std::vector<int> v( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    array_show( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );
    std::endl( std::cout );

    array_show( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );
    std::endl( std::cout );


    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as above

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Instead of the algorithm std::copy you can write a loop yourself. For example

```
template <class InputIterator>
void array_show( InputIterator first, InputIterator last )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' '; 
    }           

    std::cout << std::endl;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your function to accept the start and the end iterators. You can then use your function for any form of iterables

```
template<typename Iter>
void array_show(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    // how to define mi????
    for (Iter it = begin; it != end; it++)
        std::cout << " " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

You can then call your function as follows

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> vec= { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6 };
    int arr[] = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6 };
    array_show(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    array_show(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));


}
```

In case you would want to pass the array as a reference as well as a vector, you should create two different function overloads to support both. This probably looks like your intention as your function signature intended to accept the size as well as the object.

```
template<typename Ty, size_t size>
void array_show(Ty(&arr)[size])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << " " << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

and subsequently call it as

```
int arr[] = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6 };
array_show(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use it the way you showed:

```
template<class arraytype>
void array_show(arraytype array, size_t arraySize)
{
    auto end = &(array[arraySize]);
    for (mi = &(array[0]); array != end; ++array)
        std::cout << " " << *mi << std::endl;
}
```

As `vector` has defined `operator[]`, construct `&(array[...])` will work for both `vector` and plain array.

But preferably:

```
template <class Iter>
void array_show(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    for (Iter it = begin, it != end; ++it)
        std::cout << " " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

and then:

```
vector<int> vi;
int ai[100];
//fill with data

array_show(vi.begin(). vi.end());
array_show(ai, ai + 100);
```